# Django Design question: How to break down the code properly

Tags: python, django, design-patterns

I would like to build an app which has some UI but a lot of backend activities.
Basically, I would like to loop over list of files in a directory. for each such file, I would need to get a user feedback what is the type of the file, and then based on the file type, read all it's records and do some work on each.
So the code will basically do:
Loop over all the files in a directory:
for each file --> Show the user the file name and then the user can select the right file type
Loop over all records in this file
Do Something

My question is where should the loop over the files should be? In the view or in the html?
If it is in the view, the HTML rendering to ask the user to select file type will be moving the control to the client (html) and then (after after user selection), It will return as a POST reply (outside the loop), right?
So should the loop over the files be in the html itself?

What should be the right breakup between the HTML and the View?

Comment: What do you mean by "loop over all the files in a directory"? How can that work in terms of user interaction? Where is this directory?  Do you understand the difference between front-end and back-end? HTML is just the presentation layer to the user. All logic always happens in the view and models.

Comment: Hi, Yes, I know the difference between presentation layer and the backend layer, however, as I'm new in Django, I don't know how to maintain the state/context of the loop, as in the loop I need to render the html to allow the user to select the file type, and then, when he will click the Submit, how can I get back to the loop to go to the next iteration?   I'm new in Django, so I may be complicating thing for nothing, but I would like to understand how to do it.

Comment: There are two ways to keep track of state: have models that are saved to your database so that at each step you record state of the models. Or use a session variable (which in the background is also saved somewhere, in the db by default). See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/).

Comment: Thanks Dirkgroten, I will learn and try to implement it.